# A question about the use of a certain algorithm $(M|I)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm studying for a test and I came a cross at least two uses for the following 'algorithm' (I don't know what to call it):

Say we have the matrix $M$, placing the matrix in this form $(M|I) \ or \ (I|M) $ (that's a matrix) then doing rref on on $M$ will yield some other matrix on the other side where $I$ was.

My question is what is this matrix and what can we learn from it ?

What are all the uses for this algorithm ?

Comment: Since putting an extra column at the end of $M$ to solve a system of equations, e.g $(M|b)$ to solve $Mx=b$, is called the *augmented matrix*, I have referred to $(M|I)$ in classes as an *extended* augmented matrix.  I've no reference to support that this might be a standard term, but it seems reasonably clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M$ is invertible, then row-reducing $(M|I)$ to $(I|Q)$ will yield the inverse of $M$! In other words, $M^{-1}=Q$. This is because row-reducing means multiplying on the right by elementary matrices. Denote $\mathcal E_i$ as an elementary matrix. Then:
$$\begin{align} MM^{-1}&=I \\ \mathcal E_1MM^{-1}&=\mathcal E_1I=\mathcal E_1 \\ \mathcal E_1\mathcal E_2MM^{-1}&=\mathcal E_1 \mathcal E_2 \\ &\vdots \\ \underbrace{\mathcal E_1\dotsb\mathcal E_qM}_{\large I}M^{-1}&=\mathcal E_1\dotsb\mathcal E_q \\ M^{-1}&=\mathcal E_1\dotsb\mathcal E_q \end{align}$$

Here, $\mathcal E_1,\dots,\mathcal E_q$ are the elementary row operations you use on $M$ to achieve the identity, hence the underbrace. This is probably the most useful way of computing the inverse of a matrix!

**Edit**: Additionally, say instead of $I$ you use any invertible matrix $P$, with columns $u_1,\dots,u_n$, and $M$ has columns $v_1,\dots,v_n$. Then, if we row reduce $(M|P)\leadsto (I|Q)$, we'll have simultaneously solved each of the $n$ systems of equations $$u_j=x_{1j}v_1+\dotsb+x_{nj}v_n|_{j=1,\dots,n}$$
(Using arguments similar to the above) So, we'll have the coefficients of each $u_j$ expressed as a linear combination of the $v_i$'s. In effect, we have $$u_j=\sum_{i=1}^n{x_{ij}v_i}$$
In other words , the entries of $Q$ are $\{x_{ij}\}_{{\large{1\le i\le n}} \atop {\large{1\le j \le n}}}$, so $Q$ is the change of basis matrix from basis $(u_i)$ to $(v_i)$. Notice the above case is a special case, where $I$ represents the standard basis.

Comment: Thanks. I saw another use of this operation with finding the transformation matrix or coordinates. Can you shed some light on that ?

Comment: If you use another invertible matrix other than $I$, say $P$, the result is the matrix that changes coordinates from the columns of $P$ to the columns of $M$. I've edited to add the details. Do they shed some more light?

Comment: Yes, great explanation!